# WINDOWS 10 - after I remove ubuntu, GNU error and i try everything, i've got BootOrder not found

Tags: windows, ubuntu

my pc shows System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults. Reset System and it's have infinity loop

what should i do?? I try everything and it hasnt success

Comment: Please see [this](https://superuser.com/a/1513253/529800) answer

Answer (score 0):

If yours is EFI,
     just go to EFI boot menu(It is accessible all time unless there is hardware failure). You can go there with appropriate key for your motherboard(It is usually F2 or del). Change the boot order in the menu and set windows boot manager first.

If yours is Legacy BIOS.(I dont know about Legacy BIOS like I do with EFI, but you can try)

Reinstalling windows from live usb should fix the problem with least effort(Unless the upgrade option without data removal is available). This is the simplest way of all.

You can also reinstall ubuntu to fix this temporarily if there is important information in your C drive. The grub will auto detect OSes and will allow booting windows. Take data backup and reinstall windows.