# Running diskpart and chkdsk on BCD partition

Tags: boot, windows-10, partitioning

I am trying to run `chkdsk` on the boot partition. I have been advised that this is a hidden partition that I first need to unhide using `diskpart`.

I found this [explanation](https://superuser.com/questions/449245/option-to-set-a-drive-letter-missing/989187#989187).

But this is what I am seeing. It is unclear to me where the BCD parition is.

How do I proceed? Are there better tools to be checking a disk with such as gparted or are there even custom utilities for repairing the boot partition?

[image: diskpart]

To put this in context, this question arose out of an answer that I received from an earlier [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1072056/unable-to-boot-windows-10-with-recovery-drive-after-blue-screen-recovery-error).

Answer (score 0):

What we see from diskpart output:

- Disk 0 is GPT style (disk 1 seems to be USB? in MBR style)
- System BCD is always on EFI System partition (partition 1 on disk 0 in your case)

---

You can map partition 1 after selecting it using `assign`.

Exit diskpart.

Then on command prompt you can run `chkdsk`.

---

There is also a very easy solution for mapping EFI System:

[`mountvol <Drive>: /s`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc772586)